# Laravel group routing issue

Tags: laravel

Laravel routing issue while using the contrain on parameter with routing without  `->where('id', '[0-9]+');` working but I need to add this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{id}'], function () { 
    Route::post('/edit', 'User\InstituteController@editInstitute');
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Which causes the following error

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object

Comment: You forgot to add id as parameter in the function() [more here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) change it to this `function($id){}`

Comment: added  but same error Call to a member function where() on a non-object

Comment: I don't believe you can apply where filters to route parameters on groups. You could try a `Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way. This way you can define multiple where conditions. Not tested but hope you get the idea.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '/{id}',
    'where'  => [
      'id' => '[0-9]+'
    ]
  ], 
  function () { 
    Route::post('/edit', 'User\InstituteController@editInstitute');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`where()` can only applied on `get`, `resource` and `post` etc.
See documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) and the section `Regular Expression Constraints`.

So:

```
get('user/{name}', function ($name) { 
    // code
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');

// post request
$router->post(...)->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+']);

// put request
Route::put(...)->where(...);
// delete request
$router->delete(...)->where(...);
```

And apply for groups see the awnser of @izupet

For global contraints you could use `Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+')` or `$router->pattern('id', '[0-9]+');`

Or see the `Router` class: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`

Comment: Thanks , i am following izzputs answer ,but thank you for teaching the usage of patterns